# How to use different comparators for the same priority queue?

Tags: c++, comparator, priority-queue

Depending on the conditions, I need to use different comparator classes on the same `vector<Objects>`

```
priority_queue<Object, vector<Object>> pq;

if (something...)
    priority_queue<Object, vector<Object>, Comp1> pq;
else if(...)
    priority_queue<Object, vector<Object>, Comp2> pq;
else
    priority_queue<Object, vector<Object>, Comp3> pq;

... All further code works on pq & does not change on the conditions.
```

How do I achieve this? I found out that changing comparators is not suggested as it leads to undefined behavior, but here I only need to initialise different comp based on certain conditions.

Comment: The question is super vague, but if you need to change the comparison "based on certain conditions" why not just include those conditions in your comparison function?

Comment: That seems a nice idea! :D

Comment: That would be problematic. You may have to take a fresh look at your requirements and find a different solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `std::function<bool(Object const&, Object const&)>` as your comparator, and then pass in the appropriate functor during construction.

```
//typedef just void repeating myself over and over
typedef priority_queue<Object, vector<Object>, std::function<bool(Object const&, Object const&)>> queue_type;
queue_type pq;
if (something...)
    pq = queue_type{std::less<Object>{}};
else if(...)
    pq = queue_type{std::greater<Object>{}};
else
    pq = queue_type{...};
```

Note, failure to provide a valid comparison function during construction of the queue will cause an exception to be thrown when any operation that relies on comparison is made.

Comment: While that provides a syntactically correct solution, it is not semantically correct. Using `std::less` for part of the `priority_queue` and `std::greater` for another part of the `priority_queue` will most likely result in strange behavior.

Comment: It's not part.  You're creating a new priority queue, and replacing the original one (erasing all contents).  If you want to reorder a queue, then you cannot use std::priority_queue.  This works if you say, want to create a queue, with a sort order based on ascending or descending, and then fill it an use it entirely.  There is no way to update the comparison operator without replacing all of the contents of the queue

Comment: I see. I hope the that's what the OP needs.

Comment: How would you go around doing it with Comparator classes instead of functions?

Comment: Also, I'm coming across this error (i.e arg. 3 is invalid) while using this snippet of code error:

` template argument 3 is invalid
   typedef std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>`, std::function<bool(int const&, int const&)> queue_type;`

I'm using `int` instead of `Object` just for proof of concepts here.

Answer (score 2):

As alternative you may rewrite code as:

```
template <typename Comp>
void foo()
{
    priority_queue<Object, vector<Object>, Comp> pq;
    // ... All further code works on pq & does not change on the conditions.
}
```

and then

```
if (something...) {
    foo<Comp1>>();
} else if(...) {
    foo<Comp2>>();
} else {
    foo<Comp3>>();
}
```